# how to pass a particular value from a list of item of model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am just trying to pass a particular value from a model's list of items to an action called Editnew

Here is my code

```
 @Html.TextBox("txt", item.orderquantity, new { onchange @Html.ActionLink("Editnew","Foodtoorder",new{id =item.orderid})})
```

I want to pass that particular item.orderid along with newly entered text box value. please help me.

Comment: You want to submit the value as the user types something?

Comment: @WannaCSharp
 i want to pass item.orderid and the "txt" that is the value entered in the textbox also, total two parameters to pass

Comment: You only have one textbox in your view?

Comment: @WannaCSharp
i have multiple text boxes according to list of items in model.i want to use the onchange method of textbox, ie,after entering some values into the textbox i want to pass the entered value of that particular text box along with the items.orderid, also there are somany items.orderids are there according to the list of the model

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach(var items in Model){
<input type="text" class="tb" data-val-orderid="@items.OrderId"/>
}

<script>
$('.tb').on('keyup',function(){
 var enteredVal=$(this).val();
var orderId=$(this).attr('data-val-orderid');
var Url='your action method url';

$.ajax({
url:Url,
type:'POST',
data:'data to send to the controller method',
success:function(){
//logic to handle response from the controller
}
});
});
</script>
```

Above mentioned ajax call would be ideal in ur situation.